# Search and replace String from html file in perl

Tags: bash, perl, shell

I am very beginner for perl.I have to search a string `John` from a html file and I have to replace the text.I have done and the text has been replaced but it is not saving in the file.I have attached the code which I have tried.Thanks!.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 my $file = 'index.html';
 open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n"; 
 while (my $line = <$fh>) {
 chomp $line;
 if($line =~ /John/){
 $line =~ s/John/Bush/ig;
 print $line;
 }
 }
 close($fh);
```

Comment: Redirect STDOUT to your output file.

Comment: so i have to create another file?

Comment: Yes. Opening a file and reading through it gets messy if you try and also overwrite it as you go. So best practice is don't, create a new file and copy it over once finished.

Comment: You can do a one-liner inplace substitution with `perl -pi -e 's/John/Bush/ig' index.html`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it won't be. You're reading the file and doing your search and replace on the data in memory. Then you're `print`ing the line to STDOUT.

If you want to do this, then you can use perl as a sort of super-sed using the `-pi` flags. (have a look at [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html))

Or you need to handle reading/writing data yourself.

e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = 'index.html';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";
open my $output_fh, '>', $file . ".new" or die $!;
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    $line =~ s/John/Bush/ig;
    print {$output_fh} $line;
}
close($fh);
close($output_fh);
```

Should note - you didn't need that 'if' because a 'sed style' replacement (`s/sometext/othertext`) won't do any thing if there's no initial match. You also don't need the `chomp` because that strips linefeeds - and if you're modifying the file, you will want to put them back again. (Probably!)

Edit: for bonus credit, this should do what you want as well:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/John/Bush/gi' index.html
```

Comment: Will it possible to get the html tags containing the word.<h1>John</h1>

Comment: Yes. The above will replace just the word 'John' and leave anything around it as-is. If you want to be more accurate in your filtering, you can apply different patterns.

Answer (score 2):

You have to open a new file for writing and print the replaced text to it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 my $file = 'index.html';
 open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n"; 
 open my $fh1, '>', $file."new" or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n"; 
 while (my $line = <$fh>) {
 chomp $line;
 if($line =~ /John/){
 $line =~ s/John/Bush/ig;
 }
 print $fh1 $line;
 }
 close($fh);
 close($fh1);
```

Comment: I have one more doubt.shall i ask?

Comment: If it's appropriate for a comment/question edit, then by all means do so. If it's a separate question, then opening a new one is the way forward.

Comment: @user3431651 Yes you can.

Comment: Will it possible to get the html tags containing the word.<h1>John</h1>

Comment: @user3431651 So you want to get `h1` in a variable?

Comment: Try this. It should store the tags in $1 and $2. `$line =~ s/(\<.*\>)John(\<\/.*\>)/$1Bush$2/ig;` But i am not sure if it works.

Comment: I don't know Do you get any message?